# How do I directly write to a sp.lil matrix from a parallelised calculation?

Tags: parallel-processing, sparse-matrix

I am trying to go through a dataset and perform ppmi calculations for all entries in my sparse data matrix:

> cooc_matrix = sp.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(num_vocab,
> num_vocab), dtype=np.float32)

now I take this and perform ppmi calculations:

```
from math import log
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/myfunctions/')
from ppmi_calculation import compute_ppmi, ppmi_scorer 


# start parallelising
    # protect the entry point
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        num_processes = 2
        pool = Pool(processes=num_processes)

        # List to store PPMI results 
        ppmi_results = []

        # Compute PPMI scores in parallel
        for i, j, v in zip(cooc_matrix.row, cooc_matrix.col, cooc_matrix.data):
            ppmi_results.append(pool.apply_async(compute_ppmi, args=(i, j, v, vocab_df, len_vocab, min_count, corpus_word_count)))

        # Close the pool
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    # Initialize PPMI matrix
    ppmi_matrix = sp.lil_matrix((len_vocab, len_vocab), dtype=np.float32)
    
    # Populate PPMI matrix with results
    for result in ppmi_results:
        i, j, ppmi_score = result.get()
        ppmi_matrix[i, j] = ppmi_score
        ppmi_matrix[j, i] = ppmi_score
```

It feels kind of pointless to have a sparse matrix then create a list which is very memory intensive and then return it to a sparse matrix again. I cannot seem to get the parallelised process to operate on a sp.lil.matrix instead. How do I write the compute_ppmi output directly into a sparse matrix?
Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
# start parallelising
        # protect the entry point
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            num_processes = 2
            pool = Pool(processes=num_processes)

            # Initialize PPMI matrix
            ppmi_matrix = sp.lil_matrix((len_vocab, len_vocab), dtype=np.float32)
            # or alternatively 
            ppmi_matrix = sp.coo_matrix((len_vocab, len_vocab), dtype=np.float32)

            # Compute PPMI scores in parallel
            for i, j, v in zip(cooc_matrix.row, cooc_matrix.col, cooc_matrix.data):
                     ppmi_matrix.append(pool.apply_async(compute_ppmi, args=(i, j, v, vocab_df, len_vocab, min_count, corpus_word_count)))

            # Close the pool
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

And omit the step with the list. My data are very big and very sparse and writing all the zeros to memory (--> the solution with an intermittent list ppmi_results) would require >>500GB RAM.

for reference, the ppmi scorer is from: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html

and ppmi_calculation.py:

```
from math import log


ZERO = 0

def ppmi_scorer(worda_count, wordb_count, bigram_count, len_vocab, min_count, corpus_word_count):
        if bigram_count >= min_count:
        corpus_word_count = float(corpus_word_count)
        pa = worda_count / corpus_word_count
        pb = wordb_count / corpus_word_count
        pab = bigram_count / corpus_word_count
        try:
            return log(pab / (pa * pb)) / -log(pab)
        except ValueError:  # some of the counts were zero => never a phrase
            return ZERO
    else:
        # Return ZERO to make sure that no phrases will be created
        # from bigrams less frequent than min_count.
        return ZERO

def compute_ppmi(i, j, v, vocab_df, len_vocab, min_count, corpus_word_count):
    worda_count = vocab_df.iloc[i, 0]
    wordb_count = vocab_df.iloc[j, 0]
    ppmi_score = ppmi_scorer(worda_count, wordb_count, v, len_vocab, min_count, corpus_word_count)
    return i, j, ppmi_score
```

Comment: A `sp.lil` matrix is a python object whose data is stored in two object dtype arrays, Those in turn have a list for each row of the matrix.  While it has code that sets values relatively effieciently (compared to other sparse formats), e.g `M[i,j] = v`,  it can't be shared, viewed, across processes.  And memory 'efficiency' isn't any better than with lists..

Comment: You already know how to use the value attributes of the `coo` format, `row,col,data`. `lil` is just another fromat with values stored in different arrays.  It's supposed to be good for iterative assignment, as you attempt, but for bulk assignment and memory use, it is worse than `coo`.  It probably would be better to make a `coo` matrix from the `ppmi_result` list directly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I will look into using a coo.matrix instead. However I would like to omit creating `ppmi_results`because it doesnt fit into memory. I changed my initial post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not suggesting 'appending' to a `coo` in the loop either.  There no such thing. Only list append makes any sense in the pool loop. But can it be conditional, skipped if the value part  of the result tuple is 0?  Weed out the (i,j,0) results in the pool/apply, without using any sparse tools.

Comment: I don't think you've done any serious reading of the scipy sparse package.  It's primarily designed to create large spare matrices when can then be used for matrix multiply and linear equation solving.  No format is designed to incrementally store 'sparse' data in compact memory.  The memory formats are fully described.  It's up to your own code to decide which elements are collected to later build the matrix.